# ng-click on a column in a table it redirects to second slide in ion-slide

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a designed two screen in ionic like ascreen and bscreen.In first screen(ascreen) does have ion-slide.In second screen(bscreen) does have a table.I have to click on column in a table,it redirect to first page second slide in ion-slide.

**ascreen.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="first screen">
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"> </button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar><ion-content> <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" >
ion-slide>slide 1</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>slide 2</ion-slide>
<ion-slide>slide 3</ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box></ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**bscreen.html**

```
<ion-view>
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">
<ion-nav-buttons side="left">
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-ios-arrow-back" ui-sref="app.landing">Back</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-content>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
redirect to slide 1
</td>
<td>
redirect to slide 2
</td>
<td>
redirect to slide 3
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: @miensol i have added code